# Restart bluetooth at boot time

Tags: bluetooth, systemctl

Whenever I boot up my computer (Pop!_OS 20.04), the bluetooth service is rfkill soft blocked.

In order to make my bluetooth mouse to work I have to open a terminal and `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` in order for it to work.

I've tried creating a systemctl service so I don't have to do this manually every time but it doesn't work.

This is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description= restarting bluetooth service

[Service]
ExecStart=systemctl restart bluetooth

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also make it executable (`sudo chmod u+x restart-bluetooth.service`) and enable it and start it:

```
sudo systemctl start restart-bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl enable restart-bluetooth.service
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

I just fixed this with some help.
First open terminal make yourself sudo with command:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/init.d
```

Use a text editor put this inside:

```
sleep 10
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Save this script as `BLUETOOTHFIX.sh`. Then enable to execute by terminal:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh /etc/rc3.d/S99BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
```

Comment: This appears to have been copied from somewhere, if so it could be considered as plagiarism... It also appears to be unfinished, w.r.t. the last two lines... also posted on AU, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1405640/348964)

Comment: I have been thinking about the plagiarism part of your comment for two days and I have not figured it out yet. 
this question appears near zombie status here at 10 months old where is the plagiarised answer I copied ?? Like flying accusations based on what assumptions the evidence provided is zero just to your OPINION it appears in your OPINION plagiarism with no supporting EVIDENCE and zero evidence linked. I still have to thank you tho for tidying up my answer it’s my first post and I had not understood clearly how to post code as neatly as you made it. So thank you Greenonline